# Preventing re-rendering on tab changes with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I made a screen component in my project with react native. And I'm using react navigation's material top tab navigator as a swiper.  It's a questionable decision but whatever :)

Just imagine you making a screen and, at top you have a image and at bottom you have the top tab navigator as a swiper. It's actually working fine but, everytime when i switch the tabs in the component it's re-rendering the entire component.

And of course this is fires the componentDidMounts for the child components, which causes to make requests over and over.

Is there a way to avoid this?